# Show each color of a configurable with size and color on the catalog page?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

How would I take a configurable with options size and color and when on the catalog page have it show not only the configurable product, but also a product for each color it comes in?

I know that it is possible for it to show each simple product on the catalog listing, but but that leads to it showing every product with every products size's.

For example, I have a shirt that comes in black and blue with sizes l,m,s. I want, on the product page, to have it show:

1) Configurable with options black and blue.
2) Black shirt
3) Blue shirt

But not sizes or each simple product. Almost like a mini-configurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, why not just duplicate your configurable product so it shows twice on the product list page, then change the base/small image of one product to point to your blue item, and the other to point to black.